# Recalculate Calculated Columns with Javascript

Tags: javascript, task-list, validation

Has anyone some sample javascript code to recalculate a calculated column in SharePoint 2013 tasks?
This should work on new and edit form and also with the AllItems view.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understood your question fully, but check out this article as this has one option to update a calculated column automatically.

http://www.moustafarefaat.com/MoustafaPWS/Default.aspx?pg=a7c6f024-82ee-46e6-aa8d-fc80383ec723&detail=19ba94b9-d1a4-42a8-8ae8-46ab17c93f14

You may need to modify this as per your requirement.

Also, can you put some notes on the scenario that you are trying out?

Comment: Thanks Rajesh!
I'd like to create an individual ID out of the column ID and the subject of the task. The problem is that the field ID is empty until the task will be created and the ID will be dropped out of the calculated column when you change something in the task (I saw several posts on this issue here). So i thought that it might be a solution to run a javascript which recalculates the column again if the edit form or the "AllItems" view will be opened. Or is there a better solution? (I cannot use SPD or do not have a workflow system right now).
Thanks